# Why I can access my Kubernetes deployed application through it's ClusterIP in minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have deployed a simple `NodeJS` server (which outputs `hello world`) in a docker container using `minikube`

I have assigned two services, namely `ClusterIP` and `NodeportIP`.

When I curl the `NodePortIP` from my `host` machine, I can see the output (i.e `hello world`)

When I just try to `curl` the Ip address of `ClusterIP` from my host machine, I still can see the output from my `NodeJS` server without any errors.

How this is even possible?

I think:

1.) `ClusterIPs` are only accessible through the cluster itself, that means I can be able to `curl` to the `ClusterIP` only after using `minikube ssh`. But still I can see the output even when I `curl` it from the host machine.

2.) `NodePortIps` enable to expose the application outside the cluster. But to what extent? Can someone from a different geographical area can also `curl` into that IP and access my application? Is that what **exposing the application outside the cluster means?**

**Can someone help me by describing the extent of exposure these two `ClusterIP` and `NodeportIP` are referring to?**

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the subnets and routes.

In general, if you can access a container, then you're either in the same network as the container, or there is a router or bridge between your network and the container network that manages the traffic.

So if your ClusterIPs are in the same network as the localhost, or if there is a router or bridge network that connects your localhost with the cluster network, then you can access your containers using ClusterIP. You're running minikube, so I suppose one of these is true.

In a normal k8s installation, ClusterIPs are in a separate subnet, and there are no bridges or routes that connect it to the outside network, so you cannot access containers using ClusterIP.

NodePort will open the same port on all the hosts, and as long as you can access the host via one of the networks it is on, you can reach that service.

Comment: What do you mean **NodePort will open the same port on all the hosts**. This is where i don't understand. So that means, my friend from a different country can also access the application through a NodePort?

Comment: Only if your friend can access that host.

Comment: What do you mean only he can access the host? You mean, for an example, if he can connect to my host through remote desktop connection? 
Would you just please describe the function of `NodePortIP` in a simple way?

Comment: What ports of your hosts are connectible from outside depends on your firewall rules for that host, or how traffic is managed by a load balancer if you have one in front of your network. If you have a single host with a nodeport open, and if somebody can connect to that port of that host, then they can call the service attached to that nodeport.

Comment: **hosts?????** What do you mean by that? I have only one local machine in which `minikube` installed. Why talk about `hosts` and what do you mean by them? So this is what I need to know, **NodeIP only allows you to access the service from different Nodes with in the cluster. That means you cannot still access the service from your local machine?**. For that you can use a `LoadBalancer` type service. Is that it?

Comment: Read this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ For Minikube, you have only the localhost. For normal k8s clusters, you have multiple hosts. There are multiple networks in a k8s cluster, a pod network, a service network, etc. If you can access a network, you can access the containers/services on that network. ClusterIPs for services are allocated on the service network. Pod IPs are allocated on the pod network. A NodePort is exposed on all networks.

Comment: This is really getting complex. Only if I could find a simple and understandable documentation for this.

Comment: Read about tcp/ip networking in general, routing, and container networking in particular.